# Editing a model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm developing a simple site using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I have some issue with editing a model.

Say, the model is as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }
```

I have two different user roles, for example, Admin and User. Now I'd like User to be able to edit only Login, whilst Admin should be able to edit both properties. I'm using pretty standard edit approach, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View(FindModel(id));
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UpdateModel(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

The ideas I have:

I can show the Password text field only if a user is Admin so that User won't be able to change it. However, as far as I know, MVC binding uses the id (or name, probably) of an element to bind it to a model, so User will be able to manually create a field for password modifying HTML directly and then send the data to the controller.

I can create two different Models for Admin and User, say `UserModel` and `AdminModel`, two different actions in controller, and depending on the role of a user, I will create different submit buttons for User and Admin. So, User will click on 'EditUser' button and `UserModel` won't even content Password, therefore making it not so easy to forge the password.

I can check if the pass was changed and the user is User, an error will be shown.

Other solution is to simply divide editing into two actions: edit login and edit password separately.

Could anyone give any ideas as to how to solve this and whether or not I need to protect the application from such forgery?

Comment: `manually create a field for password modifying HTML directly` what you are referring to is called [over-posting and there are a few ways to prevent it](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: you can you something like that @if (User.IsAdmin)
{    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)} else @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm aware of these methods, but none of them shows how to use model binding depending on user's role.

Comment: @DanielVorph
That's the first idea I've written, simply not add the TextBox; doesn't solve the problem, though,

Comment: @smilez probably because any attribute that role based binding is going to crazy ugly to view.

Comment: what happend if you not add Pass TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a LOT of way to do this.  To keep the code DRY I would do something like:

```
public class EditLoginVM
{
  public bool CanEditPassword { get; set; }
  public string Login { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@if (Model.CanEditPassword ) 
{
  // Show Password Textbox blah blah :)
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(EditLoginVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var updateModel = new Model();
        updateModel.Login = model.Login;

        if (/* user is admin, don't use EditLoginVM.IsAdmin!!!! */)
        {
            model.Password = model.Password;
        }

        UpdateModel(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    model.CanEditPassword = /* reset it just in case of overposting */;        

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what was wrong with me, assigning properties basing on the role seems pretty easy. 

Of course, I won't use model's property to find out whether a user is admin or not; most likely I'll use User.IsInRole method which is already defined in ASP.

Comment: Yeah I updated my code.  Most of the time I based my logic off of the model.  I changed the property to `CanChangePassword` which mean in the future you can adjust that value if other roles can change the password.  (Because being an admin really has nothing to do if you can change your password, that is logic).